# Latest Compass Gems in Jar format

Tags: java, sass, compass, dotcms

I am using dotCMS with Sass and it appears to be using an old compiler `compass-gems-0.12.2_1.jar` and I'd like to upgrade to the latest. I can't seem to find any newer compass gem in jar format. Any idea how I can obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but using the technique like the one found here: http://seanchenxi.com/java/sass-compass-jruby-single-jar
it seems that you can update this yourself

So try this:

Download the jruby jar:
http://www.jruby.org/download  - jruby-complete-1.7.18.jar
then 
from the command line, run

```
java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.18.jar -S gem install -i ./compass-gems sass --no-rdoc --no-ri 
java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.18.jar -S gem install -i ./compass-gems compass --no-rdoc --no-ri
java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.18.jar -S gem install -i ./compass-gems less --no-rdoc --no-ri

jar cf compass-gems-latest.jar -C compass-gems .
```

replace the compass jar (compass-gems-0.12.2_1.jar) that ships with dotCMS with your new compass-gems-latest.jar and give that a try.

Comment: Thanks, @wezell. I was afraid I needed to do this. Quick question, why do you need to do `sass` as well? Wouldn't `compass` gem alone install `sass` as the dependency? Also, can you actually just drop the jar and it would work without dotCMS folks changing anything? The library might not be backward compatible.

Comment: dotCMS obviously doesn't test against the .jar you've made, I think you are going to have to give it a try and see if it works.  We have put an issue in to update our compass libraries.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this sometime today :)